# how to remove correlated or duplicated variable or individuals in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following type (however very large number of variables and ind) data:

```
    mydf <- data.frame (Inv = 1:6, varA = c(1,1,1,  0,1,1),
   varB = c(1,0,1,  0, 1,1), varC = c(1,0,0,  0,1,1), varD = c(1,1,1,  0,1,1), 
     varE = c(1,0,1,  0, 1,1), varF = c(1,1,1,  0, 1,1))

mydf
  Inv varA varB varC varD varE varF
1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
2   2    1    0    0    1    0    1
3   3    1    1    0    1    1    1
4   4    0    0    0    0    0    0
5   5    1    1    1    1    1    1
6   6    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I want to do all one to one comparsion (both variables and individuals / subjects) and keep only one if they are duplicated and name of duplicated individuals / variables to different file as log:

For example in above data:

Among variables:

```
varA is exactly same as varD and varF - so I will just keep varA only in new data

mydf$varA == mydf$varE
[1]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

varB and varE has exactly same data - so I will just keep varB
varC is unique
```

Among Inv( i.e. subjects):

```
1, 5 and 6 are same  -> so just keep 1
```

**Thus the resulting output file is**

```
        mydf <- data.frame (Inv = 1:4, varA = c(1,1,1,  0),
       varB = c(1,0,1,  0), varC = c(1,0,0,  0))
  Inv varA varB varC
1   1    1    1    1
2   2    1    0    0
3   3    1    1    0
4   4    0    0    0
```

I would be able to find duplication probably by correlation matrix:

```
cor(mydf[,-1])
          varA      varB      varC      varD      varE      varF
varA 1.0000000 0.6324555 0.4472136 1.0000000 0.6324555 1.0000000
varB 0.6324555 1.0000000 0.7071068 0.6324555 1.0000000 0.6324555
varC 0.4472136 0.7071068 1.0000000 0.4472136 0.7071068 0.4472136
varD 1.0000000 0.6324555 0.4472136 1.0000000 0.6324555 1.0000000
varE 0.6324555 1.0000000 0.7071068 0.6324555 1.0000000 0.6324555
varF 1.0000000 0.6324555 0.4472136 1.0000000 0.6324555 1.0000000
```

Ca we automate this process ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
dat <- mydf[-1]
cMat <- abs(cor(dat)) >= (1 - .Machine$double.eps^0.5)
whichKeep <- which(rowSums(lower.tri(cMat) * cMat) == 0)
cbind(mydf[1], mydf[whichKeep + 1])

  Inv varA varB varC
1   1    1    1    1
2   2    1    0    0
3   3    1    1    0
4   4    0    0    0
5   5    1    1    1
6   6    1    1    1
```

Comment: thanks for the great solution ....is possible to list variable that fall in same group (correlation = 1) ..so that we know what is going on that is deleted and why ?

Comment: @hijo. Sure. Something like this will get you the names: `names(dat)[rowSums(lower.tri(cMat) * cMat) > 0]`.

Answer (score 11):

You could also use [`findCorrelation`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/caret/html/findCorrelation.html) from the `caret` package:

```
findCorrelation(x, cutoff = .90, verbose = FALSE)
```

where the output is a vector of indices denoting the columns to remove.

Comment: `> findCorrelation(mydf, cutoff=0.9, verbose=FALSE)`
Error in findCorrelation(mydf, cutoff = 0.90, verbose = FALSE) : 
  correlation matrix is not symmetric

Comment: @xbsd : Little late reply but that first argument 'x' should be a correlation matrix not a data frame. In your case run findCorrelation(cor(mydf), cutoff=0.9, verbose=FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

This is a highly dubious statistical undertaking but it's not hard to identify the elements in that correlation matrix that are 1 and which are in the upper triangle.

```
cmat <- cor(mydf[,-1])
hicorr <- which(row(cmat) < col(cmat) & cmat==1, arr.ind=TRUE)[,"col"]
hicorr
#varA varB varA varD 
#   4    5    6    6 

mydf[ , -hicorr]
  Inv varA varB varF
1   1    1    1    1
2   2    1    0    1
3   3    1    1    1
4   4    0    0    0
5   5    1    1    1
6   6    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are trying to perform feature selection/dimensionality reduction. In this case take a look at [**FSelector**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/index.html) package from CRAN. In particular, there are several correlation-based filters, e.g. `linear.correlation(formula, data)`. See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Dimensionality_Reduction/Feature_Selection) for details.